# API for user private Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am able to build apps to use Cloud Firestore where the "database" is owned by myself - and effectively visible to me, with the associated costs born by myself.

Is there a way to use this service under the app user's own account.  The objectives are firstly to not have any cost to myself, and secondly to have the user's data remain private.

The application I have in mind would be a "Labor of Love" project to assist people sufffering ME/CFS and a key metric would be to let people's data remain personal and private.  But as I have no way (or desire) to monetise this application, I also need to keep it cost free to myself.

I guess my question is where to find any API that will allow the mobile app to "create and access" Cloud firestore in the user's own Google Account.  I may just need the right search terms or a link to the documentation to be able to get started.

For what it is worth I intend to use Flutter for the development.

Comment: If you don't want to monetize the app, then you can just use the free tier of Firebase https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Comment: @SaigeethaSundar While that's a true statement the other objective in the question was *to let people's data remain personal and private* and that won't do it. The person that creates and owns the Firebase app has access to ALL the data stored in Firebase; that's how firebase works. If you want each user to be the only accessor of their data, they would have to create a Firebase account, set up the project, get the credentials and build the app based on that, which is obviously not a solution. The other option to to encrypt the data so it's not in human readable form.